# Hard drive data recovery - spins but not recognized in BIOS - PCB + ROM Swap did nothing

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I'm the neighborhood computer guy. Recently a friend came to me with a dead hard drive with all her family photos on it. Alas, she didn't do any backups. I said I could look at it, but there was probably nothing I could do.

Model number is the Seagate ST3750528AS. S/N is 5VP5CCLB.

The hard drive spins up, you can hear it reading a little bit of data (typical hard drive initialization sound), but isn't detected in the BIOS at all.

After doing some research, I decided that the PCB is easy and cheap to swap, so it was worth a shot. I ordered an identical replacement on eBay. When it arrived today I swapped the ROM chip (fun SMD rework!) from the old PCB onto the new PCB, and unfortunately the drive has completely identical symptoms to before the PCB swap: it sounds completely fine - spins up, you can hear the heads reading some data, and then sits idle, still spinning.

Any ideas? I'm new to this, and she can't afford professional data recovery so I'm her best bet. The drive seems to me to be in working mechanical order, but since I replaced the electronics and it still doesn't work I'm at a loss...

Thanks!

Comment: The replacement board may not be a good match. Matching model numbers is not good enough. Drives with identical model numbers may have come from different factories and have significant internal differences. There are specific numbers that must match. I don't know the details.

Comment: @LMiller7 I matched model number, firmware code, PCB revisions. The PCBs are completely identical in every respect but the site code of the drives they came from.

Comment: Without doing the smd rework you should have swapped the whole board. It is hard to detect where the real problem is sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

This HDD died and you can't do any thing about it at home. But if still the platter and the head are healthy (still spinning) it can be retrieved by doing specialized and electronic repairs on the board with a chance nearly of 30% .

Answer (score 0):

There are some last-ditch, destructive things you can try. Don't do these if there is any chance of getting g an expert involved. Note also that these are unlikely to work.

1. Try refrigerating the drive.
2. Try baking it at low temp.

Comment: Can you elaborate? What, specifically, do you think may have gone wrong in this particular drive?

Comment: I don't wish to say what might have gone wrong - only that these techniques have worked in the past as last ditch efforts for me and others. (It MIGHT be a stiction issue or joint issue unrelated to the soldered component.)